# Using a verb like 'to finish' with different nouns

Tags: meaning, differences

Here is an example:

> 1. I finished lunch.
> 2. I finished shower.

Why is *2* incorrect?

What is the difference between these two nouns that makes the grammar different?

Comment: @NigelJ Isn't a shower also an activity, e.g. "I took a shower"?

Comment: Compare: "I finished my lunch" and "I finished my shower." Seems okay. I'd suggest instead that this has to do with article usage.

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin 'I took lunch'. No article.